# Symfony2 Using Amazon Load Balancers and SSL: Error on isSecure() Check

Tags: symfony, ssl

Hi I'm running into an issue where Symfony2 doesn't recognize the load balancer headers from Amazon AWS, which are need to determine if a request is SSL or not using the **requires_channel: https** security configuration.

By default Symfony2 $request->isSecure() looks for "X_FORWARDED_PROTO" but there's apparently no standard for this, and Amazon AWS load balancers use "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO".

I see the cookbook article for setting trusted proxies in config, but that's geared around whitelisting specific IP addresses and won't work with AWS, which generates dynamic IPs.  Another feature, setting the framework config to include **trust_proxy_headers: true** is deprecated.  This breaks my app by forcing endless redirects on the pages that require SSL-only.

Answer (score 2):

You can now change the headers using `setTrustedHeaderName()`. This method allows you to change the four headers used throughout the file.

```
const HEADER_CLIENT_IP    = 'client_ip'; // defaults 'X_FORWARDED_FOR'
const HEADER_CLIENT_HOST  = 'client_host'; // defaults 'X_FORWARDED_HOST'
const HEADER_CLIENT_PROTO = 'client_proto'; // defaults 'X_FORWARDED_PROTO'
const HEADER_CLIENT_PORT  = 'client_port'; // defaults 'X_FORWARDED_PORT'
```

The above, taken from the Request class indicate the keys available for use with the aforementioned method.

```
// $request is instance of HttpFoundation\Request;

$request->setTrustedHeaderName('client_proto', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO');
```

That said, at the time of writing, using `"symfony/http-foundation": "2.5.*"` the below code correctly determines whether or not the request is secure whilst behind an AWS Load Balancer.

```
// All IPs (*)
// $proxies = [$request->getClientIp()];

// Array of CIDR pools from load balancer
// EC2 -> Network & Security -> Load Balancers
//  -> X -> Instances (tab) -> Availability Zones
//  -> Subnet (column)

$proxies = ['172.x.x.0/20'];

$request->setTrustedProxies($proxies);

var_dump($request->isSecure()); // bool(true)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're right the `X_FORWARDED_PROTO` header is hardcoded into [HttpFoundation\Request](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.php#L60) while - as far as i know - overriding the request class in symfony is currently not possible.

There has been a [discussion/RFC](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/7453) about this topic here and there is an open [pull-request](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/7461) that solves this issue using a `RequestFactory`.